# Greek theta instead of lower case þ (Icelandic) in TexStudio

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use Icelandic characters in TexStudio. My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,float} 
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{gb4e}
```

I can get both upper and lower case ð Ð, but only upper case thorn (Þ). When I type lower case þ, TexStudio returns it as the Greek letter theta.

This is peculiar. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The culprit is `gb4e`. I'm looking at the code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For reasons that cannot really be known, the `gb4e` package has a line that says

```
\def\th{\ifmmode\theta\else$\theta$\fi}
```

Probably for historical reasons when the code was ported years ago: looking at the code, it really seems a straight port from a plain TeX macro package.

The `\th` command is defined by the LaTeX kernel (precisely it is in the LaTeX Internal Character Representation, LICR) and should never be redefined.

You can fix the issue by saving and restoring the meaning of `\th`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\let\LATEXth\th
\usepackage{gb4e}
\let\gbth\th
\let\th\LATEXth

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

ð Ð Þ þ

\end{document}
```

[image]

I redefined the `gb4e` provided `\th` to `\gbth` in case you need it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much!